# How to troubleshoot a Lenovo laptop key taking ~5 minutes to start working?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I've recently started noticing an issue on my 2016 Lenovo ThinkPad where, when I open up the laptop after taking it out of my backpack and log in, certain keys don't work for a few minutes.  I've noticed the Backspace and Tab keys seem to most-consistently have this issue, but I think also the 't' key and possibly other keys I haven't noticed yet (I haven't yet thoroughly checked all keys to see which ones have the issue).

What seems bizarre to me is that once the affected keys start working, they seem to work totally normally.  So I feel like it wouldn't be a hardware issue, but I don't know a lot about hardware and maybe it is?  I do think I may have had the keyboard replaced at one point (I only vaguely remember), so I'm wondering if maybe it's just a low-quality keyboard component that's wearing out or something.

It also doesn't seem to be that anything I do causes the keys to start working.  I can just leave the laptop on its own for a few minutes and when I come back to it the keys will be working.

I've had this laptop for years and never had this issue.

Comment: A laptop in a back pack may be subject to twisting forces. Two things:  make sure the keyboard cable is properly seated; and, consider a genuine Lenovo keyboard replacement.

Comment: Also consider a swollen battery pressing on the keyboard while in backpack.

Answer (score 0):

"I've had this laptop for years" - laptops don't last forever.

It seems like yours has developed a bad connection somewhere that
gets "fixed" when the laptop heats up. From your description this
has some connection to the keyboard.

The only recommendation I can offer is to very carefully open the laptop,
clean it up, and press gently on any connection you see.
If this doesn't help, and as you don't mention being comfortable with
hardware repairs, a professional repairman would be helpful.